# About a strategy to check smoothness of an algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, jacobian

I want to ask about the Jacobi criterion for checking smoothness of this projective variety (i'll write the coordinates as $x,y,z,w$), I need to find singular points of:

$$
   xyz + xyw +xzw+ yzw=0
 $$

I think that I can't parametrize this variety so I can't check if it is smooth using the fact that maybe is isomorphic to something easyier. But I think that use jacobi criterion is really long ...so how can I proceed? It exists a smarter way?

Comment: Jacobian criteria is really long? Its a hypersurface...

Comment: At least it fit in a comment: Let $f=xyz+xyw+xzw+yzw$. The point $p=(x_0,y_0,z_0,w_0)$ is singular iff $f(p)=0$ and $(\partial f/\partial x_i)(p)=0$. In particular $$(\star)\enspace f(p)-x_0(\partial f/\partial x)(p)=y_0z_0w_0=0$$
from which one element of $\{y_0,z_0,w_0\}$ is zero, say $y_0$. Considering the equation $(\star)$ with $y_0$ we get one element of $\{x_0,z_0,w_0\}=0$, say $x_0$. Finally considering $(\partial f/\partial x)(p)=y_0z_0+y_0w_0+z_0w_0=z_0w_0=0$ we get one element of $\{z_0,w_0\}$ equals zero. Reciprocally if three coordinates are zero the Jacobian vanish.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's a great idea!!!